# parse error before ')' token in wrapper function

Tags: c++, c, syntax-error, inline-assembly

I'm trying to compile the following wrapper function for a system call for my Operating Systems class and I keep getting the following compilation error.

Just to clarify, this code is from a HW assignment where we needed to add some functionality to the task_struct. It's Linux 2.4 running on a VM.

```
syscall_files.h: In function `get_all_events_number`:
syscall_files.h:58: parse error before ')' token


int get_all_events_number(){
    long __res;
    __asm__ volatile (
            "movl $245, %%eax;"
            "int $0x80;"
            "movl %%eax, %0"
            : "=m" (__res)
            : "%eax"
    ); << line 58
    if((unsigned long)(__res) >= (unsigned long)(-125)) {
        errno = -(__res);
        __res = -1;
    }
    return (int)(__res);
}
```

Can anyone see the the problem? I've been trying to figure it out for the past 30 mintues and I have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: I think you missed `;` after `%eax` (`"%eax;")

Comment: @H2CO3 - I've added it (by hand since it was from a VM and I couldn't copy-paste)

Comment: @haccks - Which line are you reffering to?

Comment: I am referring to last line of `__asm__volatile`.

Comment: Which line is line 58?

Comment: @haccks - In Inline asm, assembly statements need a `;` but not for optional Input/Output operands & clobbered registers(here its is `%eax`).

Comment: Is it c++ in some linux box ?

Comment: @twalberg - I've added it to the post. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: The only thing that stands out to me is that I'm not sure "%eax" is a valid input constraint - but I'm sure I haven't completely memorized the list of all the valid constraints... If you mean that to be a clobber designation, then you're missing a ':'...